# Image navigation overlay arrows (next & previous)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, css

I'm trying to create an overlay image navigation arrows for the image in my gallery, I've found some scripts and it works fine, except it requires me to provide the image dimensions to work good, HTML code

```
<div id="article_image">

    <img alt="" src="image.jpg" />

    <div id="article_image_overlay" style="height: 361px; width: 620px">

        <a href="prev" class="prev" title="Previous image"><span style="height: 361px; display: inline"/></a>
        <a href="next" class="next" title="Next image"><span style="height: 361px; display: inline"/></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

and the CSS styles

```
#article_image {clear:both;margin:7px 0 10px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;overflow:hidden;}
#article_image img {display:block;}

#article_image_overlay {position:absolute;z-index:2;top:0;left:0;}
#article_image_overlay a {position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:50%;height:100%;background:url('blank.gif') repeat 0 0;}

#article_image_overlay .next {left:auto;right:0;}

#article_image_overlay span {float:left;width:75px;height:100%;display:none;zoom:1;background:url('blank.gif') repeat 0 0;margin:0 0 0 12px;cursor:pointer;}
#article_image_overlay .next span {margin:0 12px 0 0;float:right;}

#article_image_overlay .prev:hover span,#article_image_overlay .prev.hover span {background:url('arrow_left.png') no-repeat 0 50%;}
#article_image_overlay .next:hover span,#article_image_overlay .next.hover span {background:url('arrow_right.png') no-repeat 100% 50%;}
```

Everything works fine, but I don't have access to image dimensions (directly), and I want to remove it from the HTML code so it works on pure CSS/JS solution, I need some help here, thank you :)

Comment: Is it an option to get the image size using JS?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, you need to "load" the images before running your code, something like this:

```
$('.myDiv img').load(function() {
   // run slider here...
});
```

You will notice images need to be fully loaded in order to run the slider, this may not look very good, so, you will probably want to hide ".myDiv" while loading, and show it once images are in place (please refer to [jquery toogle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for this).

I hope it helps!

mb

Comment: Can't it be done without JS? I found out that .load for images isn't very reliable and sometimes dimensions are set to 0

Comment: I am not aware of any other way to do it. Do you think load() will affect you? How?